# Execute extra functionality when selecting an external context menu in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating an Eclipse plugin where I want to add some pre and post processing tasks that need to be executed automatically when a context menu is executed, this context menu is provided by a third-party plugin so it is not possible for me to modify it, does Eclipse have a mechanism that I can use to intercept the call to a context menu to execute some tasks before and after the actual context menu is executed?

Comment: I guess it's not a _global_ or _retargetable_ action according to [Eclipse FAQ How do I hook into global actions, such as Copy and Delete?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_hook_into_global_actions,_such_as_Copy_and_Delete%3F) or is it?

Comment: Hi, no, unfortunately is not a global action

Comment: Just fingerpointing into a possible direction: _Window_ → _Navigation_ → _Find Actions_ (Ctrl+3) gets all available actions somehow but I didn't find the piece of code yet where this is implemented in Eclipse's source. Once you get the desired action: `Action` extends `EventManager` which has [`addListenerObject()`](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/common/EventManager.html#addListenerObject(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: It seems to be `collectContributions()` in [`org.eclipse.ui.internal.quickaccess.ActionProvider`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/quickaccess/ActionProvider.java?id=a6224173af1e8b15706d80e75516898a52b90a0f). Its result contains `ActionContributionItem`s which have [getAction()](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Faction%2FActionContributionItem.html&anchor=getAction()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that with `EventManager`, as mentioned in my comments to the question, it's not working any longer.

I created a *New* → *Project...*  → *Plugin-Project* → ... → *Template: Menu contribution using 4.x API* and adapted `HelloWorldHandler`:

```
  @Execute
  public void execute( @Named( IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL ) final Shell s ) {

    //MessageDialog.openInformation(s, "E4 Information Dialog", "Hello world from a pure Eclipse 4 plug-in");

    final IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if ( window instanceof WorkbenchWindow ) {

      final MenuManager menu = ( (WorkbenchWindow) window ).getMenuManager();
      final Set<IContributionItem> result = new HashSet<>();
      collectContributions( menu, result );

      result.stream()
          .filter( ci -> ci.getId().equals( "about" ) )
          .forEach( ci -> {
            final IAction a = ( (ActionContributionItem) ci ).getAction();
            System.out.println( a.getDescription() );
            //((Action)a).addListenerObject(null);
            // The method addListenerObject(Object) from the type EventManager is not visible
          } );
    }
  }

  private void collectContributions( final MenuManager menu, final Set<IContributionItem> result ) {

    final IContributionItem[] items = menu.getItems();
    for ( final IContributionItem item2 : items ) {

      IContributionItem item = item2;

      if ( item instanceof SubContributionItem )
        item = ( (SubContributionItem) item ).getInnerItem();

      if ( item instanceof MenuManager )
        collectContributions( (MenuManager) item, result );
      else if ( item instanceof ActionContributionItem && item.isEnabled() )
        result.add( item );
    }
  }
```

#### Output

```
About Eclipse Platform
```

So, I can get an `Action` by its ID but contrary to [the doc of `Action`](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/Action.html) and contrary to the source displayed with <kbd>F3</kbd> in Eclipse (`EventManager` ← `AbstractAction` ← `Action`) it doesn't expose `EventManager`s methods ("*The method addListenerObject(Object) from the type EventManager is not visible*"). Probably since the doc of the latter reads:

> **Warning:** Do not use this class! Use [`ListenerList`](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/ListenerList.html) directly. See [bug 486067](https://bugs.eclipse.org/486067).

AFAICS if the supplier of the third-party plugin doesn't use this `ListenerList` and offer a `addListener()` in his plugin we're out of luck.